# Submenus in php and mysql directory style database

Tags: php, mysql, list, drop-down-menu, nested-loops

I've been trying to make a menu with submenus on each main item and then sub_sub_menus on each sub menu through php and mysql. I feel like i'm so nearly there but i'm new to php and mysql so i've come here for your help. 
I have been searching for hours for an answer, i've found examples of dropdown menus but none like this.

Not sure how to add an sql database here but will try to add if requested.

My php code below so far.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM library WHERE parent_id =' . $parent_id = 0);

$subResult = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM library WHERE parent_id >'. $parent_id);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                echo '<ul class="nav list">';

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                            echo '<li class="nav-item">'. '<a href="#">'.$row['mainfolder'] .'</a>'.
                              '<ul class="dropdown-content nav">';
                            while($sub = mysqli_fetch_array($subResult))
                            {
                                if($row['id']===$sub['parent_id'])
                                {

                                        echo $sub['parent_id'];

                                    $submenuItems = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT mainfolder FROM library WHERE parent_id ='. $sub['parent_id']);
                                    $items = mysqli_fetch_array($submenuItems);
                                    foreach ($items as $eachItem){
                                       echo' <li class="submenu">'.'<a class="sub" href="#">'.htmlspecialchars($eachItem, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'</li>'.'</a>'.'</ul>';
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                            echo '</ul>'.'</li>'; 


                echo '</ul>';
            }
```

Comment: you need a tree structure, and a recursive 'walker' type function to nest things properly.  Look up `nested set`, `adjacency list` or `materialized path` Hierarchical data structures.

Comment: once you get the data in a hierarchy, then you will need a function ( probably recursive ) to build the `ul > li` sets and then some proper CSS, it's not the easiest thing in the world to do... lol

Comment: parent_id = $parent_id = 0 - this doesn't strike you as odd at all?

Comment: looks fine to me, `' .... parent_id =' . ($parent_id = 0)` it could work...  I think it's moot because doing 2 simple queries wont give you a many level nested tree, in any case.

Comment: @Strawberry All my main menu items have parent_id = 0 so i'm simply selecting them. It would be easier if I could show the table.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Do you not think I can do it with this code, I feel like i'm so nearly there with it. It's been a long day. Only began learning PHP and MySQL on tuesday.

Comment: I would get rid of the sql in the loop and use a Join instead, too.  But yea there is a lot going on here.

Comment: you can do 1 level with this, a parent and a child, but doing more then that, I doubt it.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I know people don't appreciate asking for the answer on here but do you think you could point me further in the right direction?

Comment: @clearyb123 - yea give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you asked nicely, and because I like the challenge of recursive functions I decided to go ahead and help you out.

My original answer was getting a bit out of hand, so I cleaned it up.  I also did a ton of debugging, and fixed a few "bugs" that I found in my original post.

```
echo "<pre>"; //preserve whitespace

//I mocked up some arrays ('canned data') to make things easier to show and test
//order of the parents matter ( should be in the order left to right of the menu )
$parents = [
   ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'item1', 'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item1', 'parent_id' => 0], 
   ['id' => 8, 'title' => 'item8', 'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item8', 'parent_id' => 0],
];

var_export( $parents );
echo "\n\n";

//you can order children any way you want, they will still be grouped under the right parent
$children = [
    ['id' => 2, 'title' => 'item2', 'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item2', 'parent_id' => 1],        
    ['id' => 3, 'title' => 'item3', 'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item3', 'parent_id' => 2],
    ['id' => 4, 'title' => 'item4', 'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item4', 'parent_id' => 1], //not ordered
    ['id' => 5, 'title' => 'item5', 'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item5', 'parent_id' => 2, "target" => null, "css_class" => null],
    ['id' => 6, 'title' => 'item6', 'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item6', 'parent_id' => 1, "target" => "_blank"], 
    ['id' => 7, 'title' => 'item7', 'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item7', 'parent_id' => 8, "css_class"=>"test"],  
];

var_export($children);
echo "\n\n";

$lv = 1;

$html = "<ul class=\"menu menu_lv0\" >\n";

foreach( $parents AS &$parent ){
    $html = buildMenuTree( $parent, $children, $html, $lv, $lv );   //pass by refrence so no return needed
}

$html .= "</ul>\n";

var_export( $parents );
echo "\n\n";

echo htmlspecialchars( $html )."\n\n"; //htmlspecialchars for display reasons


//=========================================
//            DEFINE FUNCTION
//=========================================

//$parent is passed by refrence
function buildMenuTree( &$parent, $children, $html='', $lv=0, $indent=0 ){

    if( $lv == 1 || $lv == 2) $mode = true;

    if( !$children ) return;
    reset( $children ); //reset the array

    $t0 = getIndent( $indent );
    $t1 = getIndent( ($indent+1) );

    //css class for menu item
    $css_class = (isset($parent['css_class']) && $parent['css_class']) ? " {$parent['css_class']}" : "";
    //link target
    $target = (isset($parent['target']) &&  $parent['target']) ? "target=\"{$parent['target']}\" " : "";

    $id = $parent['id'];

    $html .= "{$t0}<li id=\"menu_item_{$id}\" class=\"menu_item item_lv{$lv}{$css_class}\">\n";
    $html .= "{$t1}<a class=\"menu_link\" href=\"{$parent['link']}\" {$target}>{$parent['title']}</a>";

    while( false !== ( $child = current( $children ) ) ){           
        //if the parents id, matches the childs parent id, then add the current child
        //as a child of parent and check it ( current child ) for any children it may have
        // add  if( ... && $limit == $lv) and pass in a $limit param to the function to limit the depth
        if( $parent['id'] == $child['parent_id'] ){
            $key = key( $children );
            //remove - to reduce array and our processing time, we can remove the current item
            //also the current item is the parent in the recusive function and therefore we
            //know it cannot be a child of itself and we wont need it in that branch
            unset( $children[$key] ); 

            //make a recursive call ( call this method again
            //&$parent, $children, $html='', $lv=1, $indent=1
            $r_html = buildMenuTree($child, $children, "", ($lv + 1), ($indent+2));

            //creante the children array if not exists
            if( !isset( $parent['children'] ) ){
                $parent['children'] = []; 

                $html .= "\n{$t1}<ul class=\"sub_menu menu_lv{$lv} parent_{$parent['id']}\" >\n";
                $html .= $r_html;
            }else{
                $html .= $r_html;
            }

            ///store the child
            $parent['children'][] = $child;

        }else{
            $next = next( $children );

        };
    }

    if( !isset( $parent['children'] ) )
       $html .= "\n";
    else 
       $html .= "{$t1}</ul>\n";

    $html .= "{$t0}</li>\n";

    return $html;
}

function getIndent( $indent, $pad = " " ){
    return str_pad("", ( $indent * 4 ), $pad);
}

echo "</pre>";
```

I tested this on Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) PHP/7.0.4) and it 100% works.

**OUTPut**

*Array Tree structure* 
Parent is passed by reference, so it's modified not returned, we need the return for the HTML

```
$parent = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'item1',
    'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item1',
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'children' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 2,
        'title' => 'item2',
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item2',
        'parent_id' => 1,
        'children' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 3,
            'title' => 'item3',
            'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item3',
            'parent_id' => 2,
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'id' => 5,
            'title' => 'item5',
            'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item5',
            'parent_id' => 2,
            'target' => NULL,
            'css_class' => NULL,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 4,
        'title' => 'item4',
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item4',
        'parent_id' => 1,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'id' => 6,
        'title' => 'item6',
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item6',
        'parent_id' => 1,
        'target' => '_blank',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 8,
    'title' => 'item8',
    'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item8',
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'children' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 7,
        'title' => 'item7',
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com/item7',
        'parent_id' => 8,
        'css_class' => 'test',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

*HTML*

```
<ul class="menu menu_lv0" >
    <li id="menu_item_1" class="menu_item item_lv1">
        <a class="menu_link" href="http://www.example.com/item1" >item1</a>
        <ul class="sub_menu menu_lv1 parent_1" >
            <li id="menu_item_2" class="menu_item item_lv2">
                <a class="menu_link" href="http://www.example.com/item2" >item2</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu menu_lv2 parent_2" >
                    <li id="menu_item_3" class="menu_item item_lv3">
                        <a class="menu_link" href="http://www.example.com/item3" >item3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu_item_5" class="menu_item item_lv3">
                        <a class="menu_link" href="http://www.example.com/item5" >item5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu_item_4" class="menu_item item_lv2">
                <a class="menu_link" href="http://www.example.com/item4" >item4</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu_item_6" class="menu_item item_lv2">
                <a class="menu_link" href="http://www.example.com/item6" target="_blank" >item6</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu_item_8" class="menu_item item_lv1">
        <a class="menu_link" href="http://www.example.com/item8" >item8</a>
        <ul class="sub_menu menu_lv1 parent_8" >
            <li id="menu_item_7" class="menu_item item_lv2 test">
                <a class="menu_link" href="http://www.example.com/item7" >item7</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

*I took the liberty to add a few things that I consider to be commonly implemented features of a navigation menu*.

- CSS Class, if a row contains `$row ['css_class']` the `<li>` will add it's value the it's classes, you can set it to `false|null` or just not have it.
- Target, if an item contains `$row ['target']` the `<a>` tag will have a target attribute with it's value, you can set it to `false|null` or just not have it.

**You can see these test cases:**

- **most items** omit `target` and `css_class` I don't like to use the word class, because it a reserved word
- **item5** has both `target` and `css_class` set to `null` any `false` value will omit these tags.
- **item6** has a `target` value of `_blank` and the link `<a target="_blank" ..` in the output
- **item7** has a `css_class` of `test` and has these classes `menu_item item_lv2 test`

**Here is a list of the classes I added to the HTML**

*UL Classes:*

- **Top level** `<ul>` will have a class of `menu`
- **Sub level** `<ul>` will have a class of `sub_menu`
- **Sub level** `<ul>` will have a class of `parent_{id}` where `{id}` is the id of the parent
- **Every** `<ul>` will have a class of `menu_lv{lv}` where `{lv}` is the nesting level

*UL Classes & Id:*

- **Every** `<li>` will have an id of `menu_item_{id}` where `{id}` is the record id
- **Every** `<li>` will have a class of `menu_item`
- **Every** `<li>` will have a class of `item_lv{lv}`where `{lv}` is the nesting level

*A Classes:*

- **Every** `<a>` tag will have a class of `menu_link`

The only catch, is do not set the `children` key in the record manually, `$parent['children']` or `$child['children']`.  I had to use it as a way to detect if children had been added yet. ( although with some work this could be refined, it didn't seem important )

This took quite a bit of work and time, so you are on your own for the CSS. But, I will say I have built many, many menus and this HTML should be really close to what you need (although, I admit, it has been a few years sense I made a nav menu).

Lastly you can test it online in PHPSanbox with this [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/72efff2c854165ef2245ce8cefdc72dcb541f94f)

Good Luck, and enjoy!

Comment: Hi thanks for this really appreciate the effort you've gone to. I haven't got it working yet but its a move forward. After adding this to my code line by line. I feel like i'm adding the data wrong as when I echo the $parents array before passing into any function I get this output:
Array11Item1 Item100

When using echo with in the foreach function before getTreeRecursive(), I get this: 

array (
  0 => '1',
  'id' => '1',
  1 => 'Item 1',
  'mainfolder' => 'Item 1',
  2 => '0',
  'parent_id' => '0',
)' '

Comment: As well as this im getting the error: Illegal string offset 'id' and 'parent_id'.

Comment: So I've fixed the illegal offset issue by removing the quotes and [ ] from the element selects. Not too sure why I had to do that. However nothing is displayed on the html now. No warnings though. I think i'd rather have warnings lol

Comment: well your first comment with that array is a single record, when you want many records you should have `[ 0=> [ 'id'=>1, ...] ]` also you are not setting the fetch mode in your query so you get both a numeric array and an associative one

Comment: You'll want to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of  `mysqli_fetch_array()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: as for the illegal offset, again your array structure is incorrect. see update.

Comment: Hi so Ive played around and managed to sort out my incoming data so a nested array is made. I'm just wondering what do I pass into the build HTML function so it displays it all on the page?

Comment: If you have it like i have in my example `getTreeRecursive( $parent, $children, $html );` the `$html` variable should contain the HTML.  You just do `echo $html;` or include it as a string etc.

Comment: When you make a function like this `buildHtml( $tree, &$html, $level )` the `&` is pass by reference.  Basically it's a single `$html` variable that is updated as it runs, normally a function creates a copy that doesn't alter the original variable's value ( unless its an object ) 
see here in the Docs http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: @clearyb123 - I make a few small updates to make it more obvious..  for the `$tree` it's the result of the first function `buildHtml( $parents, &$html, $level )`

Comment: Wow you've absolutely smashed this! This is way beyond my scope of php knowledge. I didn't realise what I was trying to do would take this much work. I wish there was a proper way to thank you. I hope this provides help for other people with the same idea as me.

Comment: The hardest part was actually indenting the HTML, that was a pain.  I program professionally with php for 6-7 years now.

Comment: Oh yea one of the bugs had to do with where I had `next` and `unset` the basic tree recursion is some stuff I wrote at work the other day, I'll have to look at that and see if I have the same error there.  basically doing `unset` was like advancing the array to the next element so it was skipping some nodes, in certain situations, because next was being called even when calling unset.  If you look the next call is now in the else condition.  My work stuff uses a more advanced tree model `materialized path`, instead of an `adjacency list` so it might not be an issue  which is why I missed it.

Comment: `adjacency list` is just a parent child relationship, like the above, a `materialized path` instead tracks all elements by using a path like this `item_lv3.path = |1|2|`  2 is the parent of 3 and 1 is the parent of 2.  This model is better because I can tell that 1 is the root when pulling 3 out, with an adjacency list I only know that 2 is the parent.

Comment: you can also query it easier because you can do `SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE path LIKE '|1|%'` and pull all the children of `1` etc. With just a parent child you cant pull `3` without first having `2`. The bars at the front and back keep it from matching things like  `1%` matches `13|20` on the `1`, but because of the bars `|1|%` doesn't match `|13|20|`.  For a menu though it's not likely you would need a partial pathway.  The stuff for work was a message wall with nested comments.

Comment: It's nice to know you've had 6-7 years experience as I'm only on week 2 of php and mysql experience but learning from the best!

Comment: Yea I learned a lot off of SO over the years, I don't usually ask questions though, sometimes it still comes in hand.  I just answer questions when I need a break from coding ... lol ... plus it helps me learn stuff I wouldn't normally do.